# 400 Bad Request in POST to API

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am trying to make a very simple WinForms application with JWT authorization. It takes the inputted values for video games from the user and, using POST, inserts it into my API that's connected to SQL. However, I keep getting the bad request error even though I went over the code numerous times. I tested the exact same POST request on Postman and it works just fine there.

```
private void btnPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    VideoGame videoGame = new VideoGame(
        tbName.Text, 
        tbGenres.Text, 
        tbPlatforms.Text, 
        tbPublisher.Text, 
        tbDeveloper.Text, 
        dtpReleaseDate.Value, 
        tbDesc.Text,
        nudPriceInEuro.Value);

    DataContractSerializer serialization = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(VideoGame));
    MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(mStream);
    serialization.WriteObject(writer, videoGame);
    writer.Close();

    byte[] serviceData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mStream.ToArray()));

    string key = *my key goes here*;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://localhost:5000/api/VideoGames");
    zahtjev.PreAuthenticate = true;
    zahtjev.Headers.Add("Authorization", key);
    zahtjev.Method = "POST";
    zahtjev.Accept = "application/xml";
    zahtjev.ContentType = "application/xml";
    Stream data = request.GetRequestStream();
    data.Write(serviceData, 0, serviceData.Length);
    data.Close();

    try
    {
        HttpWebResponse answer = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream answerData = answer.GetResponseStream();

        DataContractSerializer deserialization = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(bool));
        bool successAdded = (bool)deserialization.ReadObject(answerData);

        if (successAdded)
        {
            lblSuccess.Text = "Success!";
        }
        else
        {
            lblSuccess.Text = "Unsuccessful!";
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        using (var stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An HTTP error won't be related to your SQL Server connection.

Comment: can you also paste the postman content?

Comment: There's not much postman content. I set the same URL, headers and POST method and I send some values in xml format in the body and it just returns the ID of the newly inserted video game.

Comment: Hi, @CrookedMan . I’m trying to understand your code, but  i’ve not seen where you set the headers, **zahtjev** into your **request** object. Also, 4XX ERRORS refer to problems on client’s side but not server side (5XX). If you aren’t set the headers you might get an 4XX ERROR.